# Linq to entities OrderBy()

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list with addresses and each address has a 'From' property. I want to order them on that property using Linq.

This is what I have:

`var orderedAddresses = addresses.OrderBy(?what goes here?);`

Comment: "Does not work" is not an error description that will get you far. Please provide an [mcve].

Comment: Can you expand on "that does not work". What's the exact error? Is it a compiler error or a runtime error?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, but it's solved already :)

Answer (score 1):

This should be the code you are looking for assuming that your field is `From`

```
var orderedAddresses = addresses.OrderBy(x => x.From);
```

To OrderBy two columns you can use

```
var orderedAddresses = addresses.OrderBy(x => x.From).ThenBy(y => y.AnotherField);
```